# How to hide a View programmatically?

Tags: java, android

In my application, I have 2 `LinearLayout`'s right above each other. Via a menu option, I want to be able to make the bottom one disappear, and have the top one drop down over the disappeared `LinearLayout`.

The problem is, I have no idea on how to do this in Java.

It doesn't have to be animated, I want to hide the `Layout` on return of another activity (the menu), in `OnActivityResult`. The menu `activity` sets a `boolean` on which I check in `OnActivityResult`, and according to it's value I determine if I need to hide or show the bottom `Layout`:

```
// Only change value if it is different from what it was.
if(mUseVolumeButtonAsPTT != resultData.getBoolean("UseVolumeButtonAsPTT")){
    mUseVolumeButtonAsPTT = resultData.getBoolean("UseVolumeButtonAsPTT");
    if(!mUseVolumeButtonAsPTT){
        // Hide lower LinearLayout.
    } else {
        // Show lower LinearLayout.
    }
}
```

Can anybody give me a hint or a link on how I should do this?

Answer (score 347, accepted):

You can call `view.setVisibility(View.GONE)` if you want to remove it from the layout.

Or `view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` if you just want to hide it.

From [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html):

> **INVISIBLE**
>
> This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes. Use with `setVisibility(int)` and `android:visibility`.
>
> **GONE**
>
> This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes. Use with `setVisibility(int)` and `android:visibility`.

Comment: Can the user still interact with it if it is set to view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) ?

Comment: Can an activity, for instance, make changes to a view if it is set to GONE?  I'd imagine you could if it's set to INVISIBLE.

Comment: What about in RelativeLayout? Views positions are depending each other. I wonder what will happen after a view gone.

Comment: @ErPragatiSingh please always put link from where you copy-paste, and keep the answer similar to how the OP wanted to say. :)

Comment: @Sufian thanks, it all from android developer official site.

Comment: Use `view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` to restore it.

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
linearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Kotlin Solution

```
view.isVisible = true
view.isInvisible = true
view.isGone = true

// For these to work, you need to use androidx and import:
import androidx.core.view.isVisible // or isInvisible/isGone
```

### Kotlin Extension Solution

If you'd like them to be more consistent length, work for nullable views, and lower the chance of writing the wrong boolean, try using these custom extensions:

```
// Example
view.hide()

fun View?.show() {
    if (this == null) return
    if (!isVisible) isVisible = true
}

fun View?.hide() {
    if (this == null) return
    if (!isInvisible) isInvisible = true
}

fun View?.gone() {
    if (this == null) return
    if (!isGone) isGone = true
}
```

To make conditional visibility simple, also add these:

```
fun View?.show(visible: Boolean) {
    if (visible) show() else gone()
}

fun View?.hide(hide: Boolean) {
    if (hide) hide() else show()
}

fun View?.gone(gone: Boolean = true) {
    if (gone) gone() else show()
}
```