# Starting a Fragment without UI

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have this code in my activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Fragment workerfragment = new XMLworker();
    android.app.FragmentManager fm= getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragtrans = fm.beginTransaction();
    fragtrans.add(workerfragment, "work");
    fragtrans.commit();
  }
```

The fragments name is XMLWorker. It doesnot have a UI and i use it to parse some xmls.

On this line of my code

```
 fragtrans.add(workerfragment, "work");
```

I get the error

The method add(Fragment, String) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (Fragment, String).

why? What am i doing wrong?

EDIT: 
is it because i am using

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The method add(Fragment, String) in the type FragmentTransaction is
>   not applicable for the arguments (Fragment, String).

The error means that type mismatch:

In your case `fragtrans` refers to the native `Fragment` support while `workerfragment` to  `Fragment` from the support package. 
Check you import. You are using mixed imports for fragment from the `support package` and the native one.

Instead of

```
 android.app.FragmentManager fm= getFragmentManager();
```

you should use

```
FragmentManager fm =  getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the standard, built-in `Fragment` APIs with the support.v4 APIs which should only be used for apps that target older Android versions (API version 4+ as its name implies).

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.my_layout, container, false)

    ...

    binding.root.visibility = View.GONE
    return binding.root
}
```

GL

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5756190/5279996)