# What kind of "floating" Android view does Foursquare use for it's Activity Feed?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, foursquare

On the Foursquare activity screen, a map is displayed at the top of the scrollable activity feed, and the text appears to "float" above the map.  When the map is tapped it expands to fill the screen.  What kind of Android views are they using here?

[image: Activity feed with expandable map]
[image: Full screen map]

Comment: [HierarchyViewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html) is useful for questions like these.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a FrameLayout, with the map fragment below and a listview above, being the first element of the list an empty transparent rectangle. When you click that first element an animation is triggered to hide the listview and set the map's configuration.

I'm trying to achieve a similar screen. That's the general idea, not sure yet about the details, I'll add some code later if I can.

Answer (score -2):

Can't be certain, but I'm 99% sure that they are using the Google Maps api, with markers added. Check out this link for more information: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

Comment: I'm asking about the first screen - how do they have the activity feed floating above the map?

Comment: You can change the size of the map view, they have used layouts, probably a RelativeLayout, so as to place the map above the brown background and then place the first view on top of the map.

Comment: when you tap on the map it expands to fill the screen (show in 2nd screenshot).  Is that possible with RelativeLayout?

Comment: Yes, what you would do is set the layout containing all of the non-map elements to visibility View.Gone, please look here for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756136/how-to-hide-a-view-programmatically Also please remember to accept my answer if I have helped you

Comment: RSenApps, you should try the app to fully understand the question. It's more complicated than that.