# configure Button programmatically doesn't work

Tags: android, button

i go a button:

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_menu_topic"
            style="@style/dialog_menu_topic"/>
```

with a style reference:

```
<style name="dialog_menu_topic">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentRight">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentTop">true</item>
    <item name="android:text">@string/menu_button</item>
    <item name="android:onClick">menuButtonClicked</item>
    <item name="android:visibility">visible</item>
```

This activity is declared as a Dialog:

```
<style name="dialog_style" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

And if i simply do:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myActivity);

        Button menuButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialog_menu_topic);
        menuButton.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
}
```

Nothing happens. I tried with getting the layoutparams, add a rule where i set visibility to gone and set the params to the button. But the button is showing up again and again. Any help is appreciated.

The app isn't crashing and the button isn't hiding as he should do. Attention: Style and ID of the Button got the same Name, but they are at a different Location, so they can have the same Name that's not the Problem! Any help is appreciated.

**Update** Button.setVisibility(int value) Needs an integer. Both Button and View.GONE returning the same integer.. that's not the Problem and yes i tried it with View.GONE, even that it was not necessary...:

```
11-27 14:56:24.538: E/Button id Button.Gone(27826): 8
11-27 14:56:24.538: E/View id View.Gone(27826): 8
```

Logcat Output of View.GONE und Button.GONE...

**Update** When i use my onClick method of this Button to setVisibility it works!:

```
public void myOnclickFromMenuButton(View v){
    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

But if i use it at my normal onCreate-Method like:

```
View myButtonView = (View) findViewById(R.id.dialog_menu_topic);
myButtonView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

again nothing happens.... it's really a bad joke... ;//

**Update** my menuButton where i setVisibility to gone and my View v from the onClick method have exactly the same id:

```
11-27 18:48:56.867: E/menuButton.getId(12417): 2131361795
11-27 18:49:00.850: E/v getId(12417): 2131361795
```

From the v the Button disapears but in the normal onCreate it won't!
Please Need help..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide a View programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756136/how-to-hide-a-view-programmatically)

Comment: A 2 second search on this site would have returned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756136/how-to-hide-a-view-programmatically

Comment: @user3427079 two seconds of thinking would have returned that both View.GONE and Button.GONE return the same integer 8! ;) So that's not the Problem... Updated question

Comment: @user3427079 next time please read and think before you mark as duplicate. It could prevent other users giving me Support because they think it's a duplicate! I flaged both of your comments!

Comment: You are declaring visibility visible in the style, maybe that's it? Have you tried removing that since it's the default state and is redundant?

Comment: @user3427079 i tried with and without. Same issue. It must be something different. I also removed style and just declared in plane XML-layout file. same issue. it is really confusing.

Comment: What do you mean by "declared it in plain xml"? The visibility is visible?

Comment: @user3427079 i mean i set the configuration of the button where the button is "created". In the layout.XML file not in the style XML-file.

Comment: So you are setting visibility to visible in your xml declaration?

Comment: @user3427079 No, i set it in style but i also removed style and Setting it in layout.XML. and also tried without Setting visibility.. man i don't get why it is not working!...

Comment: By the way, you seem to be doing things to the dialog layout inside a different onCreate which would then be completely ignored when firing the dialog

Comment: @user3427079 Bro, what things? I think you missunderstand something.. the whole activity is decalred as Theme.Dialog as mentioned in the question. So that onCreate must be the onCreate of the Dialog....

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 menuButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Updated question! That's not the Problem!

Comment: I think it is because of the setVisibility in the style. You would have to remove the style if your really want to set the View to GONE. SOmehow the style is overwriting your default setVisibility that you set for the Button. If you understand me. In short I think you should remove the setVisibility from the style.

Comment: I tried but logically this can't be the Problem or how you can resize a button for example if you Need to set a width at the beginning. It's the same with the visibility

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try `menuButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Comment: Updated question! That's not the Problem!