# How to hide the component of another activity using boolean flag in android?

Tags: android

In an android application having two activity, one activity is Login Screen and second Activity is SignUp page with a fragment(signup form). when user login on some condition I redirect to Activity which contains a fragment. so I want to hide some component using flag.

How can do that please help?

Comment: you want hide some views on certain condition?

Comment: yes, like textlabel and button

Comment: `if(true){myView.setVisibility(View.GONE)}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide a View programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5756136/how-to-hide-a-view-programmatically)

Comment: But how should I use flag of another activity in second activity and his fragment

Comment: Use shared preference. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional statement. As mentioned below,

```
if(yourConditionalForSettingViewsNotVisible) {
        yourView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Hope that helps you.